# How to embed video next to block element

Tags: html, css

I have created a wrapper for a vertical list. As you can see my list is displayed as a block element, what I would like to do is embed video next to it within the containing wrapper, but no matter how I try I cannot.

I had though that if I specified a `width`, `height` etc to the `div` containing my embedded video it would take care of it. But alas, tis not to be.

Would some kind and scholarly person please have a look at my humble code and proffer a solution.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navcontainer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">video_1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">video_2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">video_3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">video_4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">video_5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">video_6</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">video_7</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">video_8</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">video_9</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">video_10</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="video_embed"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* style for lists*/
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:.2em;
}
div#navcontainer ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 18%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div#navcontainer li {
    margin: 0 0 .2em 0;
}
div#navcontainer a {
    display: block;
    color: #036;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 9em;
    padding: .2em .8em;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #036;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #036;
}
div#navcontainer a:hover {
    background-color: #369;
    color: #FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #036;
    border-left: 1px solid #036;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
div#video_embed {
}
/* end style for lists*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is display the `div#navcontainer` and the `div#video_embed` as `inline-block`.

In this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ACXF9/) I've also put a `vertical-align: top;` on both the `#navcontainer` and `#video_embed`. I've added an `outline` and `width` and `height` to the `#video_embed` just to make it visible in the example.

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: my dear sir, i thankyou soooo much for this, i had not been aware of the inline-block value and its awesome that you took the time to make it clear - kind regards robbie